# Trigger ReactCSSTransitionGroup on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I've been trying to figure out how to trigger the react css transition group on scroll. Say i've got a stack of components and this example gets rendered off screen :

// component.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'
import './style.css'
export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      title: ['an off screen title']}
    }
    render() {
    const displayText = this.state.title.map(i => <h1 key={i}>{i.title}</h1>)
      return (
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName='atxt'
            transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>
          {displayText}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      )
    }
}
```

// style.css

```
.atxt-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.atxt-enter.atxt-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
}
.atxt-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.atxt-leave.atxt-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
}
```

I want the transition group to be triggered when it enters the **View** and not just when the component is initially rendered.
I've been mulling over the docs and exploring pre-made libraries / components to accomplish this but have not found anything that doesn't involve bringing in huge animation libraries... I know *deep* in my cockles there is a way to do this, hence, asking the pros here. Cheers ya'll.

Comment: You mean when it is visible to the user (i.e is inside the viewport?).

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Viewport

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just throwing out an idea:

Use https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint to add your component to the DOM when you scroll to a specific element.

`<Waypoint onEnter={this.handleWaypointEnter} onLeave={this.handleWaypointLeave}/>`

In your `handleWaypointEnter` , add your `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup>...</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>` to the dom.  This should work, according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) it applies animations upon entering the dom.

Comment: Yup. Using Waypoint currently. lol. I'm mostly just interested in the actual mechanism of scroll triggering components to load and unload. I will need to figure out a more concise way to show / ask now that i've had more reading. You are absolutely right though! Waypoint. Solved!